# login POST form with cURL

Tags: curl, authentication

I am trying to login to the website www.centralgreen.com.sg/login.php using cURL (first time user of cURL)

I used the Tamper plugin for Firefox, and I have 4 POST inputs:

```
login=mylogin
password=mypassword
Button_DoLogin.x=33
Button_DoLogin.y=6
```

I tried to use curl again using

```
curl.exe --data 'login=mylogin&password=mypassword&Button_DoLogin.x=33&Button_DoLogin.y=6' www.centralgreen.com.sg/login.php?ccsForm=Login
```

But the login apparently doesn't go through (the output of this command is the same form, filled with only the password, and an error message **The value in field Username is required.**)

Here is the full list of info I get from Tamper

```
Host centralgreen.com.sg
User-Agent Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:2.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/4.0
Accept text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept Language en-us,en;q=0.5
Accept Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept Charset ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Keep Alive 115
Connection keep-alive
Referer http://centralgreen.com.sg/login.php
Cookie PHPSESSID=65fbxxxxxxx02694e3a72xxxxxxxx; Valley_ParkLogin=04E203A459FCxxxxxxxA2DCD9AAE5B9678G08C04F1952155E2482xxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Is there anything I do wrong? How can I pass the login through the POST form?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try using the `-F` option instead of `--data`.

http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-F

Basically, this changes the content type header to:

```
Content-Type: multipart/form-data
```

This may give you a better result.

Comment: Could you advice on how to use it? I have tried with no success curl.exe --form 'login=mylogin;password=mypassord;Button_DoLogin.x=10;Button_DoLogin.y=8' www.centralgreen.com.sg/login.php?ccsForm=Login

Comment: same for curl.exe -F 'login=mylogin' -F 'password=mypassword' www.centralgreen.com.sg/login.php?ccsForm=Login

Comment: Hmm, that isn't the problem then.  Can you post the full HTTP headers for both sides using the form **and** cURL, so we can see the differences?

Comment: Thank you for your help, may I ask you how I do that (I am relatively new to cURL so I am not familiar with some terms)

Comment: Use a packet sniffer such as Wireshark, or a proxy such as Fiddler.

Comment: Note that it is uppercase F, lowercase corresponds to --fail

Comment: Fixed.  Thanks for catching that!